# Does the .css() method in jQuery support changing rgba values?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `<div>` which has a rgba css value (transparent), which I want to change on a click of a button which is in a different `<div>`. The problem is that I am changing the color to a hex value and I can't seem to get rgba to work.
Code will be posted only if needed. My question is if .css() supports rgba

Comment: Try it out and tell us.

Comment: yes code was needed

Comment: it does support rgba values.

$("#asdsa").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
you have to put the whole rgba statement in quotes, and I didnt before, because I am sutpid :D s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var value1=$('#themeBackground1').val();
var opacity=$('#themeOpct1').val();
var rgbData=hexToRgb(value1);
value1='rgba('+rgbData.r+','+rgbData.g+','+rgbData.b+','+opacity+') !important;';
selector.attr('style', 'background-color:'+value1);
```

Comment: turned out that it does support rgba values without any hickups, I was just dumb. look at my comment on the post itself. Still I believe you and I will give you the correct answer :D (I will test it out later tho)